# PHPMailer exception error

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmailer

I've written my own Code Igniter model for sending emails. All was fine until recently when I started to get this error:

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class phpmailerException in /home/mysite/public_html/subdir/application/libraries/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php on line 2319

I'm using:

CodeIgniter 2
PHPMailer 5.1

I've tried the following to resolve it:

- Added "$mail->SMTPDebug  = 0" to turn off errors.
- Added:    "$mail->MailerDebug = false;"
- Modified the PHPMailer to only show    errors when SMTPDebug is turned on.
- Looked for and removed any echo    statements
- Added try / catch blocks Tried adding / removing: $mail =    new PHPMailer(true);

Here is my controller method (company/contact) which calls my model (message_model):

```
    function contact()
    {
        //Do settings.
        $this->options->task='email';
        $this->options->change = 'sent';
        $this->options->form_validation='';
        $this->options->page_title='Contact Us';

        //Import library
        include_once('application/libraries/recaptcha/recaptchalib.php');//Include recaptcha library.

        //Keys for recaptcha, stored in mainconfig file.
        $this->options->publickey = $this->config->item('recaptcha_public');
        $this->options->privatekey = $this->config->item('recaptcha_private');      

        //Form validation
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name_field','Name of problem','trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[100]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('desc_field','Description','trim|required|min_length[10]|max_length[2000]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_field','Your email address','trim|required|valid_email');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('recaptcha_response_field','captcha field','trim|required|callback__check_recaptcha');

//If valid.
        if( $this->form_validation->run() )
        {
  //Set email contents.
            $message="This is a message from the contact form on ".$this->config->item('site_name')."<br /><br />";
            $message.=convert_nl($this->input->post('desc_field'));
            $message.="<br /><br />Reply to this person by clicking this link: <a href=\"mailto:".$this->input->post('email_field')."\">".$this->input->post('name_field')."</a><br /><br />";

  $options = array('host'=>$this->config->item('email_host'),//mail.fixilink.com
            'username'=>$this->config->item('email_username'),
            'password'=>$this->config->item('email_password'),
            'from_name'=>$this->input->post('name_field'),
            'to'=>array($this->config->item('email_to')=>$this->config->item('email_to') ),
            'cc'=>$this->config->item('email_cc'),
            'full_name'=>$this->input->post('name_field'),
            'subject'=>'Email from '.$this->config->item('site_name').' visitor: '.$this->input->post('name_field'),
            'message'=>$message,
            'word_wrap'=>50,
            'format'=>$this->config->item('email_format'),
            'phpmailer_folder'=>$this->config->item('phpmailer_folder')
            );

  //Send email using own email class and phpmailer.
            $result = $this->message_model->send_email($options);

            //Second email to sender
  //Set email contents.
            $message="Thank you for your enquiry, we aim to get a reply to you within 2 working days.  In the meantime, please do follow us on www.facebook.com/autismworksuk";

            $options = array('host'=>$this->config->item('email_host'),//mail.fixilink.com
            'username'=>$this->config->item('email_username'),
            'password'=>$this->config->item('email_password'),
            'from_name'=>$this->input->post('name_field'),
            'to'=>$this->input->post('email_field'),
            'full_name'=>$this->input->post('name_field'),
            'subject'=>'Email from '.$this->config->item('site_name'),
            'message'=>$message,
            'word_wrap'=>50,
            'format'=>$this->config->item('email_format'),
            'phpmailer_folder'=>$this->config->item('phpmailer_folder')
            );

  //Send email using own email class and phpmailer.
            $result = $this->message_model->send_email($options);           

            //Set result.    
            if($result==-1)
                $this->session->set_flashdata('result', ucfirst($this->options->task).' was not '.$this->options->change.' because of a database error.');
            elseif($result==0)
                $this->session->set_flashdata('result', 'No changes were made.');
            else
                $this->session->set_flashdata('result', ucfirst($this->options->task).' was '.$this->options->change.' successfully.');

            //Redirect to completed controller.
            redirect('completed');
        }

//Validation failed or first time through loop.
        $this->load->view('company/contact_view.php',$this->options);
    }
```

Here is my model's method to send the emails. It used to work but without any changes I can think of now I get an exception error:

```
    function send_email($options=array())
    {
        if(!$this->_required(array('host','username','password','from_name','to','full_name','subject','message'),$options))//check the required options of email and pass aggainst provided $options.
          return false;

        $options = $this->_default(array('word_wrap'=>50,'format'=>'html','charset'=>'utf-8'),$options);

try
{        
  if(isset($options['phpmailer_folder']))
    require($options['phpmailer_folder']."/class.phpmailer.php");
  else
    require("application/libraries/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");//Typical CI 2.1 folder.

  $mail = new PHPMailer();
  $mail->MailerDebug = false;

  //Set main fields.
  $mail->SetLanguage("en", 'phpmailer/language/');
  $mail->IsSMTP();// set mailer to use SMTP
  $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;  

  $mail->Host =     $options['host'];
  $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;     // turn on SMTP authentication
  $mail->Username = $options['username'];
  $mail->Password = $options['password'];
  $mail->FromName = $options['from_name'];//WHo is the email from.
  $mail->WordWrap = $options['word_wrap'];// Set word wrap to 50 characters default.
  $mail->Subject =  $options['subject'];
  $mail->Body    =  $options['message'];        
  $mail->CharSet =  $options['charset'];

  //From is the username on the server, not sender email.
  if(isset($options['from']))
    $mail->From = $options['from'];
  else
    $mail->From = $mail->Username;  //Default From email same as smtp user

  //Add reply to.
  if(isset($options['reply_to']))
    $mail->AddReplyTo($options['reply_to'], $options['from']);

  if(isset($options['sender']))
    $mail->Sender = $options['sender'];

  //Add recipients / to field (required)
  if(is_array($options['to']))
  {
    foreach($options['to'] as $to =>$fn)
      $mail->AddAddress($to, $fn);
  }
  else
  {
    $mail->AddAddress($options['to']); //Email address where you wish to receive/collect those emails.
  }

  //Add cc to list if exists. Must be an array
  if(isset($options['cc']))
  {
    if(is_array($options['cc']))
    {
      foreach($options['cc'] as $to =>$fn)
        $mail->AddCC($to, $fn);
    }
    else
    {
      log_message('debug', '---->CC field must be an array for use with Message_Model.');
    }
  }

  //Add bcc to list if exists. Must be an array
  if(isset($options['bcc']))
  {
    if(is_array($options['bcc']))
    {
      foreach($options['bcc'] as $to =>$fn)
        $mail->AddBCC($to, $fn);
    }
    else
    {
      log_message('debug', '---->BCC field must be an array for use with Message_Model.');
    }
  }

  //Alternative text-only body.
  if(isset($options['alt_body']))
    $mail->AltBody=$options['alt_body'];
  else
    $mail->AltBody = htmlspecialchars_decode( strip_tags( $options['message'] ),ENT_QUOTES );//Strip out all html and other chars and convert to plain text.

  //Plain/html format.
  if(isset($options['format']))
  {
    if($options['format']=='html')
      $mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // set email format to HTML
  }     

  //Send email and set result.
  $return['message']='';

  if(!$mail->Send())
  {
   $return['message'].= "Message could not be sent.<br />\n";
   $return['message'].= "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo."\n";
   $return['result'] = 0;
  }
  else
  {
    $return['message'].= "Message has been sent successfully.\n";
    $return['result'] = 1;
  }
}
catch (phpmailerException $e)
{
  log_message('error', '---->PHPMailer error: '.$e->errorMessage() );
}
catch (Exception $e) 
{
  log_message('error', '---->PHPMailer error: '.$e->errorMessage() );
}
        return $return;
    }
```

Comment: use `require_once`

Comment: Ok that worked but I dont' know why. I can only find one place where I included the code. Thanks! You didn't add this as an answer though so I'll have to credit the other guy who got there a little later.

Comment: it is one place, but you call the function several times. Thus that line is executed several times

Comment: Yeah I can see it now. I'm sending out two separate emails.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically one of two things is happening:

1. You are "including" your PHP code twice somewhere, causing the 2nd time to generate the redeclaration error
2. You are using "phpmailerException" somewhere else, besides your model. Have you tried to do a "find all" in your IDE for ALL calls to "phpmailerException" - perhaps you used this name in another area for another exception?

Answer (score 11):

```
if (!class_exists("phpmailer")) {
require_once('PHPMailer_5.2.2/class.phpmailer.php');
}
```

This Code will clear this issue 100%..

Answer (score 1):

require_once("class.phpmailer.php") is better.

Mukesh is right that require_once will solve Sift Exchanges answer #1.  However, there is not need to check if the class exists as require_once does that.

Comment: No longer something I'm working on, but thanks anyway, maybe It'll help someone out.

Comment: Hi virsunen, where should that be added? I have the same conflict beween two plugins. I have used if(!class_exists){} but when it will be updated, changes will disappear. Do you know where should i add the require in order not to lose the changes? Thanks a lot